# How to add a new mail account to the Windows 8 Mail app?

Tags: windows-8

Is it possible to use a different email account in the Windows 8 "Metro" Mail app? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, open the Charms bar by hitting <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or moving your mouse to the upper or lower right corner of the screen. Then, select Settings → Accounts → "Add an account".

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps to get Yahoo Mail/Gmail on Windows 8:

1. On Windows 8 Mail App, move your mouse to either top or bottom left corner to access the sidebar
2. Click 'Settings' >> 'Account' to retrieve the list of active accounts
3. Click 'Add an Account' >> 'Other Account'
4. Choose 'IMAP' from the drop-down and enter your yahoo mail/Gmail id and password.
5. Windows 8 will configure the rest for you