# Why isn't there a Accounts setting in the Windows Mail app?

Tags: windows-8, gmail, email-client

I'm trying to add Gmail to my Windows 8 mail app, following these instructions:

[How to add a new mail account to the Windows 8 Mail app?](https://superuser.com/questions/469415/how-to-add-a-new-mail-account-to-the-windows-8-mail-app)

However, under Settings for Mail, I only have Permissions and Rate & Review, no Accounts.  What am I missing, here?

Comment: are you logged into a local or a microsoft account?

Comment: If the above comment wasn't clear enough, you need to have logged-in thru a Microsoft Account to truly access (say link other accounts, ...) any of the built in Windows 8 Apps such as People, Mail, Calendar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use the Windows 8 mail app with Exchange without adding a Microsoft Account?](http://superuser.com/questions/484137/can-i-use-the-windows-8-mail-app-with-exchange-without-adding-a-microsoft-accoun)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to log in through an existing Microsoft account for any network related Windows 8 apps.

If you have ever used an android phone you might have seen that it needs you to log in to gmail account once for you to access the play store, sync contacts, sync calendar etc.

Its a similar thing here. You need a MS account for some apps like Calender and Mail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign in with a *Microsoft Account* to use the **Mail** app.

[image: Mail App]

If you have two accounts (one Microsoft account and one Non-Microsoft account) associated with your Mail app, and if you try to remove the Microsoft account (to be left with only the Non-Microsoft account), the option that you get is **Remove all accounts**.

[image: Mail App remove account settings]

So to answer your question, you can **NOT** use the Mail app without first signing in to a Microsoft account. You'll get the **Accounts** option once you add a Microsoft account.

After you add a Microsoft account, the Settings charm will have an **Accounts** option, which you can use to add other Mail accounts.

You can however, turn off notifications for the Microsoft account, and keep notifications on for the other account(s).

Answer (score 0):

You need to log in through an existing `Microsoft account` for any network related Windows 8 apps.You need a MS account for some apps like Calender and Mail.

Answer (score 0):

To add another account in the Windows Mail app...First, you need to open the mail app. then, open the Charms menu and then click on settings...Now, can see the "Accounts" option there and you can add the another Email account

Comment: This does not answer the question.